# programmatically create test with junit?

Tags: junit

I'm going to develop a Class for accessing mysql db. It looks something like this -

```
class DB {

public void update(String,String) {....}
public void delete(String,String) {....}
.
.
.

}
```

Now...I would like to unit test each method of this class. Instead of writing unit tests for each method..is there any way to create unit tests programmatically ?

I tried doing this -

```
DB db = new DB();
Method method = db.getClass().getMethod("method name",String.class,String.class);
method.invoke(db,"params");
```

this is working, but how do I create a junit test for each method in the DB class ?

Comment: How will you test anything by generating the tests ?

Comment: I'm going to read method parameters from some config/xml file and pass into the methods. This is part is done and is working

Comment: you should have a look at parametrized tests. However i still don't see what you are going to test : I mean you will have to compare some output to expected values and I don't see how you will do that.